# NSUserDefaults not simply saving high score

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

Its supposed to be that when my player reaches a new high score, it'll show it on the GameOver scene, but in this case, its not doing that. I have all of my NSUserDefaults in a separate .swift file.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

class GameState {

    var score: Int
    var highScore: Int
    var stars: Int

    class var sharedInstance :GameState {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = GameState()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    init() {
        // Init
        score = 0
        highScore = 0
        stars = 0

        // Load game state
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        highScore = defaults.integerForKey("highScore")
        stars = defaults.integerForKey("stars")
    }

    func saveState() {
        // Update highScore if the current score is greater
        highScore = max(score, highScore)

        // Store in user defaults

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScoreLabel")
        defaults.setInteger(stars, forKey: "stars")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

}
```

In my GameOver scene, it I have all the text labels set up like so:

```
     lblHighScore.text = String(format: "High Score: %d", GameState.sharedInstance.highScore)
```

And in my GameScene, I have it so that it *should* synchronize when the game ends:

```
   func endGame() {
    gameOver = true


    GameState.sharedInstance.saveState() //right here
    print("saved score")
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let gameScene = GameOver(size: self.scene!.size)
    view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)

    print("new scene")

}
```

Is something missing? Will post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in your coding you may have overlooked:

You are saving as **"highScoreLabel"**

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScoreLabel")
defaults.setInteger(stars, forKey: "stars")
defaults.synchronize()
```

But trying to read as **"highScore"**

```
highScore = defaults.integerForKey("highScore")
```

You should use the same key when reading from and writing to `NSUserDefaults`

**For Future Reference...**

Personally I set static let variables when dealing with keys. So you never come to this hiccup in the future.

```
struct Defaults {
    static let HighScore = "highScore"
    static let Stars     = "stars"
}
```

and then use

```
highScore = defaults.integerForKey(Defaults.HighScore)
```

The issue was that none of the variables were being changed, code replaced with:

```
class GameState {

    var highScore: Int
    var stars: Int

    class var sharedInstance :GameState {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = GameState()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

    init() {
        // Load game state
        highScore   = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(Defaults.HighScore) ?? 0
        stars       = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(Defaults.Stars) ?? 0
    }

    func saveState(score: Int) {
        // Update highScore if the current score is greater
        highScore = max(score, highScore)

        // Store in user defaults
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: Defaults.HighScore)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(stars,     forKey: Defaults.Stars)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

}
```

Comment: That very last line doesn't want to work for some reason with the static constant.

Comment: Nothing was actually fixed tbh even though I changed everything.

Comment: I did write that from the top of my head, but I just tested and it all works fine, try it for yourself with this:

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: Defaults.HighScore)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        
        print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(Defaults.HighScore))`

Comment: Also made an update after looking through your code again - check in my answer

Comment: Okay, well thank you so much. Its still being weird and not doing anything, but I guess I can try and figure it out myself.

Comment: Can I ask how you are changing your highScore? Don't see that in your example code. Looks like it will always be 0

Comment: lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)   is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Not how you're setting it on the label, when are you setting the `highScore` and `score` variables on your `GameState`

Comment: They're all at the top of the class as integers like so: var highScore = Int

Comment: Yeah we can see you are initiating the variables as 0 but where are you changing the highscore and stars to be something else.

Comment: you know what, I actually don't think i am. How would I do this?

Comment: I didn't think so, so your user defaults are working just always zero

Comment: Im thinking id have to add another something to one of my constants, but i have no idea.

Comment: I think you need to rethink what you are trying to achieve with your application before continuing.

Comment: Im just trying to make the high score show up on my GameOver scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94756/discussion-between-zappidev-and-rae-tucker).

Comment: We got there in the end, glad I could be of assistance

Comment: Thank you again. Hope it wasn't too much trouble(: